# Periodically update question/answers

Tags: discussion

As we know SO and all other stackexchange networks having so many questions since past few years.

As day by day technology update and some of them may be deprecated and removed from support (probably removed from world!!). So isn't it necessary to rewrite question/answers as per new update.

Should we have to think to add new category in "review" section for this?

P.S. this applies only for very older questions which are no longer use or that version of language or technology has been removed.

Comment: Not sure what a new review queue would add... old questions can receive new answers, and it does happen all the time

Comment: There are very few technologies which are outright "removed". It's pretty darn common to have some old version of some old code running on some old machine for years and years. The maintainer of such code probably really won't appreciate you removing some reference solution to a problem he'll face down the line. The only thing that's important is to be explicit about what version some solution is applicable to, not to remove or alter that solution.

Comment: @Pekka웃  - Ok guys. But I think same problem can be treated differently for different version of softwares, so might we can have answer with all possible version included. I saw some of the answer where users gave good answers with versions. I am just thinking in that manner. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last [check](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/311638) there were 15,576,628 answers and 9,320,001 questions on Stack Overflow. That is a LOT of posts to be worried about becoming outdated and reviewing.

Who becomes responsible for updating a post? Is it the person who originally wrote the post? If so, [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/631652/parixit?tab=summary) have 160 posts at this time. Are you going to constantly update all of those? What about the users that are more active? The top 4 users on Stack Overflow have between 14,000 and 31,000 posts *each*. Are they expected to update their answers *and* continue their high quality work?

Reviewing "outdated" posts is not feasible. As you mentioned, technology changes quickly. New versions are updated/released/patched constantly. There are other ways to indicating an answer is outdated.

- Post your own answer with updated information. Explain why you are posted to an old question by stating the current answer(s) are for version X and your new answer is for version Y.
- Add a comment to the outdated answer explaining why the answer is no longer accurate.
- Ask a new question, explaining that the previous question is not relevant to version Y. Explain *why* it is not relevant or risk a duplicate close vote.
- Down vote the answer. It'd be nice to post a comment explaining why you down voted, but certainly not necessary.

Comment: Oh ok. I understand and yes I think your options to overcome is good to follow. Thanks!